# Determine/evaluate if the following integral is convergent.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^0\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}dx$$

A little lost on how to do this problem.

I know that it's an improper integral but I don't really know how to take the integral itself. Also in my professor's solution he switched the lower bound to 0 and the upper bound to 1. Why did he do this?

He ends up determining that the integral is infinite and thus it's divergent but I'm unclear as to why and how.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $z=1/x$ to reduce the integral to $$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}ze^zdz$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=-\dfrac{1}{u}$ and $u=v+1$ then
$$\int_{-1}^0\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}dx=\int_1^\infty-ue^{-u}du=-\dfrac{1}{e}\int_0^\infty(v+1)e^{-v}du=\color{blue}{-\dfrac{2}{e}}$$
using integration by parts!

Answer (score 0):

You can also see that the integrand is bounded, because:
\begin{align} 
\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^x x^3 =\lim_{x\to\infty}-e^{-x}x^3= 0
\end{align} 
So you can extend the integrand to a continuous function $f$ on $[-1,0]$ so the integral of it is finite. But now that is also true for the original  integrand since it differs from $f$ in only one point.